# Enable a button after open jquery dialog with modal true

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

I want to enable a button after that i have opened a jquery dialog with option modal set to true.The button obviously is outside the dialog. I already know that this seems to be a strange request but i need this behaviour because I have a form in the dialog so after click on the button to submit the data I have to append the dialog at the end of the form and then click agin on the button that now is outside of the dialog.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine hahaha good for seo :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use te open event that is fired whenever the dialog is opened

```
$( ".selector" ).dialog({
   open: function(event, ui) { 
        $('#yourhiddenbutton').show();
    }
});
```

EDIT - you could do it like this

```
$(function() {            
    $("#dialogRifiuto").dialog({
        width: 'auto',
        autoOpen: true,
        closeOnEscape: true,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        open: function(){
            //change the z-index and position the div where you want
            $('#a').css({'z-index':  1005, 'position': 'absolute', 'top': 0 });            
        },
        close: function(){
            //go back to normal
            $('#a').css({'z-index':  1, 'position': 'static' });        
        }

    })

});
```

Comment: He may also need to change the `z-index` because it will be below and useless

Comment: what I need is enable a button blocked by modal jquery dialog (the button isn't in the dialog). With that code i can only show a button in dialog.

Comment: @RobertodeSantis i was just suggesting you to use the open event, the code was just to point out that you should do something, i didn't really got what is your use case, but i think you should change the z-index of the button or something like that

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti http://jsfiddle.net/XXG3t/ here you can find a snippet of code. I need to enable the input text that contains value pippo without close the dialog or set the dialog modal to false. I have tryed z-index with no success.

Comment: Sorry for the up vote but you have forgotten a dot in $('#a')removeProp('disabled');

Comment: @RobertodeSantis sorry if i don't get this, but you want to have the field with pippo that is modifiable when the dialog is open?Remember that the input field that is inside the dialog will not be sent to the server because the dialog takes that outside of the form

Comment: Yes I want that. I know that the input field inside the dialog will not be sent to the server, infact I'm trying to append the dialog to the form and then click again on the button dialog that now is in the form. The problem is that the modal dialog prevent the click on the button and so nothing happen. For this reasons i need to enable an input field or button disabled by the modal dialog.

Comment: Ok it work. However 'top': 0 isn't necessary. 
I'have tried to modify the html and remove manually all the layer build by jquery dialog but without z-index and position it doesn't work. A little strange no?

Comment: @RobertodeSantis no it's normal that you need to set position: absolute to work because the overlay div covers everything otherwise and the only way  around this is absolute positioning

Comment: it work even if set position to relative. Only with static position it doesn't work. However i delete from the html code the overlay div.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable the button using 
$('#myButton').removeAttr('disabled');

Comment: wow, You really need to work with your questions. you can also use `$('#button').attr('disabled',false);`